# Redirection from ZEND framework 2 Controller's Constructor

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to check for `user id` in the constructor of my ZF2 Controller and if it is not defined then want to redirect to any external `URL` or to other controller I have tried:

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute("campaign");
```

and

```
$this->redirect()->toUrl("http://example.com");
```

Both approaches give me the same error message:

> Url plugin requires that controller event compose a router; none found

Answer (score 8):

`Service Locator` is not present in the `Controller`'s constructor, but you can override `onDispatch` method inherited from `AbstractActionController`.
Use it like this:

```
public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $session = new \Zend\Session\Container('base');
            if(!$session->offsetExists('id'))
            $this->redirect()->toRoute("campaign"); and $this->redirect()->toUrl("http://example.com")

        return parent::onDispatch($e);
    }
```